# (X)HTML & CSS definitions description in computer-readable format

Tags: html, css, w3c, definitions

is there any set of HTML & CSS definitions, like list of (X)HTML tags & their available properties (both with descriptions) and so on, and CSS properties (descriptions, browsers supporting and so on) in computer readable (ie XML, CSV, INI or so) format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason they need to be machine-readable?

Comment: yes, I need them to be loaded to code analyzis tool I'm writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Document Type Declarations](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/dtd-the-document-type-declaration/)?

Comment: like that ... but more infos, like browsers suporting and so on

Comment: Quirksmode.org has compatibility charts for CSS but they're not intended to be machine readable.